# Как скрыть в инспекторе унаследованные поля родительского класса С# - Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, наследование

Данный класс `UnitState`, родительский к такому классу как `PlayerState` а он родитель класса `Ability` отвечающие за Состояние игрока и за его способности соответственно. В данном классе `UnitState` есть поля отвечающие за  базовые характеристика юнита, его прокачку, уровень и здоровье.

Юнит - в данном проекте сущность которая может иметь такие параметры.

И так как `Ability` унаследуется от `PlayerState` то я в инспекторе вижу данные поля да и в целом унаследовал их, какой способ мне нужен чтобы класс `Ability` не смог унаследовать некоторые ненужные мне поля? Или хотябы скрыть их в инспекторе движка?

> *Класс Ability и PlayerState только добавляют новые поля не трогая унаследованные поля*

Класса `PlayerState` в инспекторе

[image: Отображение класса PlayerState В инспекторе]

Класс `RageAbility` наследник `Ability` в инспекторе

[image: Отображение класса наследника Ability В инспекторе]

Класс `UnitState`

```
public class UnitState : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public struct StatsValues
    {
        public int maxLevel;
        [Space]
        public float maxHealth;
        public float damage;
    
        public StatsValues(float maxHealth, float damage, int maxLevel)
        {
            this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
            this.damage = damage;
            this.maxLevel = maxLevel;
        }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public struct LevelUpgrades
    {
        [Range(2, 100)] public int level;
        public float maxHealth;
        public float damage;
    }
    
    [SerializeField] private StatsValues _stats;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private List<LevelUpgrades> _levelUpgrades;
    
    [Header("Status")]
    [SerializeField] private int _currentLevel;
    [SerializeField] private float _health;
    
    [Header("Links")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _damagerObject;
}
```

Comment: Судя по именам классов, у вас что-то криво с иерархией... [HideInInspector] вам не подходит?

Comment: @МаксимФисман, недавно начал практиковать само наследование, и я знаю что у меня что то где то точно не так с иерархией и самим наследованием, спасибо! Предложенный способ не подходит, или мне необходимо сделать так чтобы я мог скрыть их в `Ability` и не скрывать в `PlayerState`

Comment: Это невозможно сделать, потому, что в этом нет смысла. Если вы наследуетесь, что бы унаслндовать какую-то часть функций то это просто косяк. То что у unit и ability есть level, это не значит что они должны быть родственниками. То что способность наследуется от состояния юнита само по себе звучит абсурдно.

Comment: @Yaroslav, да) я только начал практиковать наследование, и я сейчас смотрю на это решение и вижу что это очень абсурдно) Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

> какой способ мне нужен чтобы класс Ability не смог унаследовать некоторые ненужные мне поля?

как и во всех языках мира - сделать поля приватными

> Или хотябы скрыть их в инспекторе движка?

сделать поля приватными и не `SerializeField`  либо `[HideInInspector]`

Comment: Они `SerializeField`  не просто так, они мне необходимы для настройки их в редакторе, мне их нужно скрыть только в классе `Ability` и оставить их видимыми в редакторе в `PlayerState`

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev вы понимаете, как нелепо вы звучите?  "как хотябы скрыть их в инспекторе движка"    и "SerializeField нужны  для настройки их в редакторе"..........если нужно часть полей не наследовать в одном из классов, значит реализация кривая и непродуманная и надо думать ещё........

Comment: Я понимаю) От не хватки знаний, и спрашиваю есть ли какое то решение, как я понимаю, единственное решение это подумать над тем чтобы не наследоваться от PlayerState

Answer (score 0):

Сделать так,чтобы `SerializeField` и `public` переменные не видил класс наследник,можно. Я лично устанавливаю таким полям `{get;private set;}` свойства,и всё работает как надо.